# asp.net core 2.0 console application filenotfoundexception system.runtime 4.2.0.0

Tags: c#, console-application, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-virtual-machine

I created a simple console application using asp.net core 2.0.
I published it from vs2017 to a folder and copied the contents to azure vm folder.
when i run the console application i am getting the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or ass
embly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f
11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share us the content csproj? I fail to reproduce your issue. Share us detail steps to reproduce your issue. For this error, try to add `<UseNETCoreGenerator>true</UseNETCoreGenerator>` to csproj.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same exception a time ago. Check if your data are the same like in your exception, perhaps you have a wrong directory or something like this. If this doesn´t help try to clean and rebuild your solution, that helped me out. Good luck for you